# Python: Get data from URL query string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, url

So I have a string in which I have an URL.
The URL/string is something like this:

`https://example.com/main/?code=32ll48hma6ldfm01bpki&data=57600&data2=aardappels`

I want to get the `code` but I coulnd't figure out how. I looked at the `.split()` method. But I do not think it is efficient. and I couldn't really find a way to get it working.

Comment: Have you try to write a program for it ?

Comment: So you want to get the value of `code` query param?

Comment: Look into using the already-included modules like [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html). However, you could also do this simple thing with `split()` - I don't know why you are worried about efficiency before you get a solution down first.

Comment: So what is your question? If your question is: "Here is my code, it's not working, what did I do wrong" We can help. If your question is: "I want to do xyz, please write it for me" then this is the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse)  and [parse_qs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) from [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
# For Python 3:
# from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = ' https://example.com/main'
url += '/?code=32ll48hma6ldfm01bpki&data=57600&data2=aardappels'

parsed = urlparse(url)
code  = parse_qs(parsed.query).get('code')[0]
```

It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As @IronFist mentions, .split() method works only if you assume there is no '&' in the code parameter. If not, you can use .split() method a couple of times and get the desired code paramter:

```
url = "https://example.com/main/?code=32ll48hma6ldfm01bpki&data=57600&data2=aardappels"
code = url.split('/?')[1].split('&')[0]
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but the reason is obvious, OP wants the `code` query parameters not all of them...your answer just splits over `/?` which will return the second string including all query params

Comment: Well...that might work as well, but consider a case where the value of the query param, contains itself `&`?..How would you do about that?...For this, there are specific modules for such task like `urlparse`

Comment: Correct, but then you might assume data always follows code parameter and split using ('&data').

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> url = 'https://example.com/main/?code=32ll48hma6ldfm01bpki&data=57600&data2=aardappels'
>>> code = re.search("code=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)&?", url).group(1)
>>> print code
32ll48hma6ldfm01bpki
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that 'data' will be the next field in the query string after 'code'. Probably best to just read up to the '&'. Unless the 'code' is the last field in the query string, then read up to '$'. Or just use urlparse.

Comment: You're right, I already changed it to match all numbers and letters before the first "&" or the end of the url. Thanks @PaulMcGuire

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways doing this!!! Easier way is to use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html). and the other way is to use the regular expression, but experts suggest that using regular expression on URL's can be tedious and the code becomes very difficult to maintain.

Another easy way is as shown below,

```
str1 = 'https://example.com/main/?code=32ll48hma6ldfm01bpki&data=57600&data2=aardappels'
codeStart = str1.find('code=')
codeEnd = str1.find('&data=')
print str1[codeStart+5:codeEnd]
```